# Symfony 3 access_control regex expression

Tags: regex, symfony, access-control

I'm in Symfony 3.4, I want to allow access to some URLs for no authenticated users. For that I used Regex expression like bellow, but it gaves error of syntax in **security.yml** .
Expression: `- { path: ^/link/[0-9]\{0,}/download/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}`.
**[0-9]{0,}** : for numbers.
Any help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest matching *1 or more* digits rather than 0 or more, and you should use `roles`, not `role`, to define the role:

```
path: ^/link/[0-9]+/download/,
roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
```

Note that `\{0,}` matches a literal `{0,}` string as you escaped the first open brace thus corrupting the limiting quantifier.